# MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Permission -- it returned 2

Tags: django

My tests are failing saying get() returned 2 permissions.. But I have not assigned 2 permissions anywhere. In my views m inheriting PermissionRequiredMixin from django.contrib.auth.mixins and assigning permission. Below is my test setUp code, where error is showing:

```
def setUp(self):
        self.material = MaterialFactory.create()
        self.material_reorder = MaterialFactory.create(
            opening_stock=500, reorder_qty=1000)
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            'admin', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'admin')
        self.user.user_permissions.add(
            Permission.objects.get(codename="add_material"))
```

Comment: ERROR: test_modal_create_view (stores.tests.test_views.ReelMaterialModalCreateViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anand/base/tests/mixin.py", line 95, in setUp
    Permission.objects.get(codename=self.permission_codename).id)
  File "/home/anand/Envs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Permission -- it returned 2!

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36746710/edit) button to update your question. But the error is obvious. you have two permissions with the same code name. What do you expect to happen in this circumstance?

Comment: I am using default django permission: like this permission_required = 'stores.add_material' in my views. There are no more than one permission

Comment: That error shows that there are two permissions with the same code name. Its irrelevant what permissions are required

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Yes i have 2 permissions with same code name

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter what you assigned. This line is causing the error

`Permission.objects.get(codename="add_material")`

It means that you have more than one permission with code name `add_material`.

To find out what other permissions are names add_material, get into Django console

`python manage.py shell`

once in there import auth models and check the permissions

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

for p in Permission.objects.filter(codename="add_material")
    print(p.pk, p.content_type)
```

This should tell you what other models registered a permission with the same name.

Comment: permission_required = 'stores.add_material'. Like this I am assigning permission to views. there is only one permission to code name add_material

Comment: Well, obviously there is another one somewhere, otherwise your get would only return one result. I will update my answer with instructions on how to find it.

Comment: Thank you Mad Wombat.. Yes i got it.. There are 2 permissions with same codename

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above solution, you can avoid loop and just use a simple code to get other permissions form same code name as:

```
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(codename='add_material')
print(permissions)
```